# Find agle for equilibrium

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, statics

If someone could help I'd be greatful.
The data of the problem are:

- Mass of the 2 blocks : 2Kg each
- Mass of the ring: 4*Pi Kg

Find the angle theta.
I have found that the normal at the floor is : 4g(1+Pi) and that the center of mass of the ring is at (2*sqrt(2)*R)/3*Pi  from the center, but I keep getting identities when I take the momentum equilibrium about the center. I dont know what I am missing.
THanks in advance

[image]

Comment: Please show your calculations, so that we can see what you are "missing".

Comment: For recommendations of alternative sites which might be suitable see [my question was closed on phys se - can you recommend me another internet site?](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/391/) You might like to try http://physics.qandaexchange.com.